# Getting and manipulating a value of a key from an array of objects using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is a document from my profiles collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5f2ba3a43feccd0004b8698c")
    userID: "238906554584137728",
    serverID: "533691583845892100",
    username: "W.M.K",
    money: 15775,
    __v: 4,
    items: [...],
    serverName: "W-15i: Overworld",
    gladium: 7959.33,
    stocks: [{
        _id: {...},
        stockID: "605b26d309a48348e05d88c9",
        name: "GOOGL",
        amount: 1,
        desc: "Alphabet Inc's (Google) Stock."
    }]
}
```

I'm using `const profile = await Profile.findOne({userID: userID, 'stocks.stockName': stock.name})`

EDIT: For one stock, it's as easy as `profile.stocks[0].amount -=1`. But when I have multiple stocks, how do I get the `amount` and manipulate it like `amount -= 1`?

Comment: `profile.stocks[0].amount -= 1` ?

Comment: That's when I only have one stock, but when I have multiple stocks, what then?

Comment: Well it's just about looping over an array, that's Javascript 101 really. Use a `for` loop or `.forEach`

Comment: Well no, because I want to get that specific stock, not decrease the amount of ever single one.

Comment: Use `.find()` then? :) This really is a matter of simple array operations. Or a `for` loop with a `break` when you found your item.

Comment: `const profile = await Profile.findOne({userID: userID, 'stocks.stockName': stock.name})` I cannot use `.find()` because I'm trying a get key from an object, inside an array of objects, in one specific document. It's not as simple.

Comment: I mean `profile.stocks.find()`. Javascript `Array.find` method, not Mongoose `Model.findOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few ways you can go through an array of objects in mongoose... you can map through the array,  you can also use dot notation in an update.  Either way one thing you'll need to do is mark the document modified because mongo doesn't detect changes in arrays of objects.   To do this, make the changes and then use the markModified() function on the document.  It takes a parameter of the array field name that was modified.   in this case....  profile.markModified('stocks')

This is done after changes and before the save.

You can use dot notation with mongoose and you can also iterate through the array via map or forEach

The benefit of using map is that you can double it up with .filter() to filter the array for certain stocks

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by Jeremy, it is basically a matter of array manipulations.
Here is one example:

```
for(let i = 0; i < profile.stocks.length; i++) { 
 profile.stocks[i].amount -= 1;
}
```

If you just want to update the profile on your database, you could also look into some very advanced mongodb querys (I think it's called "aggregation"), but that is probably overkill.

Comment: ...or simply `break;` the loop when the desired stock is found?